# Replace a clause in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have this code

```
clause2( monopati1(X,X,Monopati,Monopati), true).
clause2( monopati1(X,Z,Monopati,Teliko_monopati),
   (  akme(X,Y),
      \+(member(Y,Monopati)),
      append(Monopati,[Y],Neo_monopati),
      monopati1(Y,Z,Neo_monopati,Teliko_monopati))).    
clause2(monopati(X, Y, Monopati),
   (  monopati1(X, Y, [X], Monopati),
      write(Monopati))).
```

and i need to replace the sentence with: "monopati1 (X, X, Monopati, Monopati)." 
With the equivalent sentence "monopati1 (X, X, Monopati, Teliko_monopati) :- Monopati = Teliko_monopati."
But i have to read them from keyboard.

So i did

```
write('Give clause to replace'),nl,
read(Old_clause),nl,
write('Give new clause'),nl,
read(New_clause),nl,
retract(clause2(Old_clause , _)),
assert(clause2(New_clause))
```

but the result is:

```
clause2((monopati1(A,A,B,C),B=C)).
```

How can i get rid of the extra parenthesis in clause2((monopati1(A,A,B,C),B=C)) so that it becomes clause2(monopati1(A,A,B,C),B=C).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! I made it finally out! I just read the `New_clause` as a list and then separated head from body!

```
choice1_1(a):- 
         write('Give clause to replace'),nl,
         read(Old_clause),nl,
         write('Give new clause like : [Goal , Body]'),nl,
         read(New_clause),nl,
         retract(clause2(Old_clause , _)),
         assert_new(New_clause).

assert_new([H|[H1|T]]) :- asserta(clause2(H,H1)).
```

Used `[H|[H1|T]]` just to insert my body without being surrounded by [].

Answer (score 0):

Well, if `New_clause` is a pair, then all you need to do is to add `(Part1,Part2) = New_clause`, before `assert` and then just `assert(clause2(Part1,Part2))`.

Comment: i tried that but when i read first head and then body , i didnt have the same vriables for monopati , Teliko_monopati and monopati , Teliko_monopati (after :- )

Comment: @cdg you wouldn't be able to restore the variable names in any case, but that's not important anyway. The important bit is the relationships between unification variables. p(X,X) is indistinguishable from p(A,A) all else being equal.